# Using ChartJs In a VueJs component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to use `Chartjs` to build and manage a chart in a Vue component, I am very confused as to where exactly in the script tags should I initialize the chart instance `var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...});` after importing the `chartjs` library?! I am also using a Vue CLI Webpack setup

1. In other words, I am not sure should I initialize it inside or outside the `export default {}` block and if its inside, should it be directly after opening the curly braces or maybe inside the `data()` function?
2. also the actual of the chart, should they be in the same scope where I initialize the chart instance?
3. it would be infinitely appreciated if anyone can also help with how to change the 
   actual values of the bars in the chart by passing values in input fields underneath the chart.

This is a test-task for a Junior Front-end dev position, any help would be just priceless :D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: its pretty easy actually. I have vue (webpack cli) app with chart js, you can create a simple chart in 20mins, but where are you stuck at? you can initialize the object inside your methods (assuming you have more than one chart)

Comment: also check this: https://github.com/misterGF/CoPilot/blob/master/src/components/views/Dashboard.vue#L176 the page uses chart https://copilot.mistergf.io and even though the code is verbose (because they generate the fake data inside  the template) you can do it simpler

Comment: thanks very much for your answer man, but I am still unable to understand the last part of the code, I am new to Vue and again i am using the webpack CLI..now, i buit the chart object and its data using the `var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...});` block, but i am stuck rendering it in the component, as per @sorxrob answer, i don't get the last part where i should use the `mounted()` to render the chart,, i did exactly like the code but its not rendering.. :S.. thanks again in advance

Comment: Call your chart rendering method insidd mounted()

Comment: i am very sorry but is there a way that I can chat with u directly, i did but its still giving me an error, do you use  any kind of social networking or chatting app? or even a whatsapp chat would be much easier

Comment: the errror now is `./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js`

Comment: just comment here and a chat link will pop up, can you share your `.vue` file which has the chart code in it and a fake data

Comment: its telling me i don't have enough reputation to chat :S

Comment: SO itself will insert a chat link and we write back and forth long enough then you can chat, don't worry

Comment: if you are here in Ukraine i'd offer you a lunch or something :D, this is really very important as it can help me land my first junior dev position.

Comment: i hope we could do chat, so far no links are inserted :(

Comment: First install the vue chartjs component like the answer suggests https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs, after that it's pretty easy

Answer (score 0):

In your component, before the `export default {}`, import the Chart module.

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';

export default {}
```

Let's say this is your `template`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <canvas id="your-chart"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>
```

then you can add a method that will create the chart:

```
methods: {
  createChart(chartId, chartData) {
    const ctx = document.getElementById(chartId);
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: chartData.type,
      data: chartData.data,
      options: chartData.options,
    });
  }
}
```

and call it inside the mounted lifecycle:

```
mounted() {
  const data = { // chartobject }
  this.createChart('planet-chart', data);
}
```

alternatively, you can use a [vue wrapper for Chart.js](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs)

Comment: thanks very much for your answer:), i built the chart using the `var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...});` and i populated my data, yet i still have a problem understanding the `mounted()` part, its not rendering on my page using your way `mounted() {
  const data = { // chartobject }
  this.createChart('planet-chart', data);
}` , could you please further clarify how it should be rendered ? thanks again in advance. this thing's really giving me hard times now :(